# Check if a number inputted in an "EditText" is in an array - Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, android-edittext

I want to know if a number that a user inputted into an "EditText" actually exists inside an array, here is my current code:

```
 final String[] gameArray = {("1"), ("2"), ("3"), ("4"), ("5")};


public void startGame(View v) {

    if (Arrays.asList(gameArray).contains((text))) {

        Outputs1.setText("You typed in: " + text + ", which is the correct number!");

    } else {

        Outputs1.setText("No number 1-5 detected, please type in a number 1-5.");

    }

}
```

When a user types in a number, it checks if that number exists inside an array by using an If-Statement, and if it does it displays a message, if it doesn't it displays another message.

Sadly, this does not work (Since it only displayed the other message even though I typed in 1-5), and the other questions and answers also did not work either.

Any response will be great.

Comment: you don't need to put `()` in your array. it should be fine.

Comment: @david Yes I know, I just like it like that for some reason, any other way you can help?

Comment: well, I don't have any other way. but, i think `()` in your array is unnecessary.

Comment: How you detect these number? Did you use textWatcher()? and what is your Edittext size?

Comment: @HelloWorld I detect these numbers in the EditText by using `text = Inputs1.getText();` and my EditText size is about the whole screen of any phone. I hope that's what you're talking about.

Comment: When I say size, it means that how many character your Edittext can get? And how you check these number? Every time user input new character or after some even like button click. And I have others question, Do you want to check that your text contain number in arrays or not? Because from your code you check that numberArray contain text or not.

Comment: Sorry for my weird grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now, you are supposed to add `.toString()` at the end of the If-Statement.

I changed: `if (Arrays.asList(numberArray).contains((text)))`

To: `if (Arrays.asList(numberArray).contains((Inputs1.getText().toString())))`

After that, it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this might help

```
 final String[] numberArray = {("1"), ("2"), ("3"), ("4"), ("5")};

    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() == 0) return;

            String text = s.toString().substring(s.length() - 1);
            if (Arrays.asList(numberArray).contains((text))) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"You typed in: " + text + ", which is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please type in a number 1-5.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but, this has nothing to do with it, I'm asking if the number the user types in exists inside the array, not the length of the input. My issue is that I want to fix this: `if (Arrays.asList(numberArray).contains((text)))`.

Comment: This code shows toast whenever the user types a number which exists in the array. To better understand you, give me the code where you fill the "text" variable.

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it, I was supposed to do: `(Arrays.asList(numberArray).contains((Inputs1.getText().toString())))`